# How can I track an APK install

Tags: android, installation, apk, tracking

I'm trying to track an APK install. When a user lands on the downloadpage (not the store), he is coming from a specific source. When user clicks on download, the APK will be installed. After it's installed, I need to map the install to the source the user was coming from before installing. Is there any good way to do this?

My plan so far: Save the user IP and screen resolutions on the download page to a database. After install, pass IP and screen resolution to the server and map with the row in the database. Is this a good way of doing this?

Hope you guys can help me.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to write a BroadcastReceiver for this which can receive the `PACKAGE_ADDED` and `PACKAGE_INSTALL` Intent:

**InstallBroadcastReceiver.Class**

```
public class InstallBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
  String action = intent.getAction();
  if(action.equals(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED)
    ||action.equals(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_INSTALL)){
    notifyServerForApplicationInstall(context, intent);

    }
   }

  private void notifyServerForApplicationInstall(Context context,Intent intent){

    //send the data to your server here
  }
}
```

Register the receiver in `AndroidManifest` file

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".InstallBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="false" 
        <intent-filter>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL" />
            <data android:scheme="package" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

**Don't forget to give this permissions in manifest :**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES"/>
```

Comment: thanks so far! Is it a good way to map the source on ip and screensize? Or are there any better ways?

Comment: First, if the receiver is not exported, it cannot respond to those broadcasts. Second, that permission has nothing to do with these broadcasts AFAIK. Third, this has no relevance to the OP's question, as `android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED` is not sent to the installed app, nor is it something that runs on the OP's Web server.

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES"/> for system app only ?

Comment: No you can use it in third party app as well.

Comment: @pyus13 Can I detect the apk installing event when it is installing before it is installed.

Comment: no, the event only be fired when application get installed completely .Let me know your exact requirement, might be I can give you a workaround or any other solution.

Comment: @pyus13 I want to detect whether the app that I downloaded(from other apps) or get(copy from a computer) is the official one, if not I will not install it. Now I have a soluting to detect the file change on phone use `FileObserver` but it can't observer all the file changes, even I implement it recursively.

Comment: what do you mean by official apps(Downloaded form Google Play or Your Own apps)? Even if you detect file change how will you identify whether its an official app or not ?

Answer (score 0):

I have prepared a BroadcastReceiver class :

```
public class newPackageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("DEBUG"," test for application install/uninstall");
    }

}
```

In the main activity, I first register a new receiver object, then instanciate button for application install.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_CHANGED);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_DATA_CLEARED);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_INSTALL);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_RESTARTED);

        receiver = new newPackageReceiver();
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
        ...

dlButton.setText(R.string.dl_button);
dlButton.setOnClickListener(new AppliDownloadOnClickListener(this ));   


@Override
public void onDestroy(){
     unregisterReceiver(receiver);
     super.onDestroy();
}
```